# Magento 2 : Show order items custom option text value in order api (/V1/orders/{id})

Tags: magento2, orders, api

I want to show order products custom option in default magento 2 api **rest/all/V1/orders/order_id** run

it looks like below as we know

[image]

I need text value of the custom option in default **single** **magento** **api** run.